# TypeError cupcake.map is not a function (react)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Tengo una duda, estoy aprendiendo react y estaba creando un sitio SPA y al crear una de las páginas me salió el siguiente error:
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JVP7D.png)
El error es un componente que voy a usar como página llamado cupcake y este llama a otro componente también llamado cupcake pero este solo será una parte de esta página, la ruta es diferente. (sé que no es una buena práctica poner el mismo nombre a dos componentes, pero solo estoy aprendiendo). (los datos los estoy extrayendo de una API)
código:

```js
import Cupcake from "../sections/cards/Cupcake"
import { useEffect, useState } from "react"


const Cupacke = ()=> {

    const [cupcakes, setCupcakes] = useState([]);
    useEffect(()=> {
        fetch("http://127.0.0.1:5500/api/db.json")
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => setCupcakes(data))
    }, [])

    return (
        <div className="ed-grid">
            <h1>Página de Cupcakes</h1>
        {
            cupcakes ? (
            <section>
                { 
                cupcakes.map(({descripcion, imagen, sabor, color, precio}) => (
                    <Cupcake
                    imagen={imagen}
                    descripcion={descripcion}
                    sabor={sabor}
                    color={color}
                    precio={precio}
                    />
                )) 
                }
            </section>
            ) : (
            <span>Cargando...</span>
            )
        }
        </div>
    )
}

export default Cupacke
```

Comment: Inspecciona la estructura `data` en `then(data => setCupcakes(data))`, parece que no es un tipo `array`.  Si puedes comparte el contenido de `data` en la pregunta. Tambien consulta las preguntas relacionadas del lado derecho, es un problema común cuando se esta aprendiendo, saludos